# How to find IP address using HTML?

Tags: html, ip-address

I am trying to find the IP address using HTML coding but I cannot. Is it possible to find the IP address in HTML without using JavaScript or PHP?

```
ping -a ip-adress
```

It displays ping only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is required - with HTML only its not possible.

Comment: Some Internet websites like wieistmeineip.de (German) have some HTML code to include which shows the IP address. Maybe that's ok for you.

Comment: <a href="http://www.wieistmeineip.de/cometo/?en"><img src="http://www.wieistmeineip.de/ip-address/?size=468x60" border="0" width="468" height="60" alt="IP" /></a> this Coding Sir? am getting ip address in the Src right?

Comment: Sir am using only the src value to get ip address, its not Workingip="http://www.wieistmeineip.de/ip-address/?size=468x60"

Comment: am Declaring Like this only sir"http://www.wieistmeineip.de/ip-address/?size=468x60"

Answer (score 1):

If Apache is set to resolve IP addresses, then you can use `<!--#echo var="REMOTE_HOST" -->`. However, it is unlikely that your host has that option enabled, because it makes requests take longer.

Comment: Should still work, since this is not Apache specific. It's a technology called "[Server Side Includes](http://www.w3.org/Jigsaw/Doc/User/SSI.html#echo)", which has been around for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it is not possible in pure HTML/Javascript.Did you need local IP of PC where browser is running on or remote PC of user which is connected to web server?

Comment: i need the users ip,Whose visited my webpage

Comment: OK, so you need server side code to accomplish this.What server software is your site running on?

Comment: It is such kind of emedded media streaming device?You should check vendor's site for this kind of information.I hope there will be some usefull info at http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?12-server-side-modules-and-code-samples

Answer (score 0):

If you insist, you can create an iframe to load the IP and the iframe page will use JavaScript or php etc.. to make the result.