# How to get local IP address in javascript html5

Tags: java, javascript, html, ip

I want to get Ip address of my machine in javascript which is further refer in my html page.
I have refer all the suggested links but I do not get any answer.
I do not want to use any link to get the IP so i tried with following line of code in my javascript

```
var ip = '<%=request.getRemoteAddr();%>';
```

or

```
var ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
var ip = Request.UserHostAddress.ToString();
```

But do not get the result.

Please help me to get the solution.I want to include this javascript in my html page and I do not want to use any link to get the IP.

`All the links I have gone through gives the external links to get the IP address and I do not want to use any external link to get the IP.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can You Get A Users Local LAN IP Address Via JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194722/can-you-get-a-users-local-lan-ip-address-via-javascript)

Comment: @ Kishor Pawar I have mention in my question that i do not want to use any link to get IP address.I have already gone through this links

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find ip Address using Html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700730/how-to-find-ip-address-using-html)

Comment: @Danny Sir, I have tried it already

Comment: @ rachana are you using JSPs?

Comment: @ codeMan no I am using HTML but if you have solution for jsp then please share it

Comment: Please do not down vote the question.

Comment: These guys do it:  http://www.whatismyproxy.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont think that there is a notion of hosts or ip-addresses in the javascript standard library. So you'll have to access some external service to look up hostnames for you.

Unless you might want to send a request to the server which returns you the host IP address!!

**EDIT**

In JSP you you can use [getRemoteHost()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteHost()) method from [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)

to get the IP address of the user.

So you can write something like this -

```
var ip = '<%=request.getRemoteHost();%>';
```

^^ the above line is JSP code, this should be part of the JSP file that you return from java servlet container like a tomcat. This does not work in static HTML pages.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do it

Comment: Why not? What does it say??

Comment: I want to get the IP in my javascript and then want to pass that ip to further  functioning. so I have wrote like this `var ip = '<%=request.getRemoteHost();%>'; ` in my java script.But it takes `<%=request.getRemoteHost();%>`as a value

Comment: Sorry, I  forgot to mention. That code should be in a JSP file and you should return that JSP file from the server. It does not work in the static HTML page. `<%=request.getRemoteHost();%>` is JSP code

Comment: it returns the host ip address. can u please let me know how to get the local machine's ip address from which the url is invoked?

Answer (score 7):

Given from [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/257/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-with-javascript-only) you can do that.

```
/**
 * Get the user IP throught the webkitRTCPeerConnection
 * @param onNewIP {Function} listener function to expose the IP locally
 * @return undefined
 */
function getUserIP(onNewIP) { //  onNewIp - your listener function for new IPs
    //compatibility for firefox and chrome
    var myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    var pc = new myPeerConnection({
        iceServers: []
    }),
    noop = function() {},
    localIPs = {},
    ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
    key;

    function iterateIP(ip) {
        if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
        localIPs[ip] = true;
    }

     //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createDataChannel("");

    // create offer and set local description
    pc.createOffer().then(function(sdp) {
        sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
            if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
            line.match(ipRegex).forEach(iterateIP);
        });

        pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
    }).catch(function(reason) {
        // An error occurred, so handle the failure to connect
    });

    //listen for candidate events
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) {
        if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
        ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(iterateIP);
    };
}

// Usage

getUserIP(function(ip){
    alert("Got IP! :" + ip);
});
```

Comment: this somehow doesnt work on IE. it says object is not supported. Is there any counterpart in IE? i really need this to find local machine ip.

Comment: This seems to work find in Chrome, but fails in Firefox, IE, and EDGE.

Comment: [No longer supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56755747/fractured-rtcicecandidate-no-longer-returning-ip)

Answer (score 2):

The cgi, written in C-language bellow, returns the list of the environment parameters, among them REMOTE_ADDR. It constitutes a base for any HTML page, providing cgi are enabled in the HTTP server (Apache2 for instance).

Just compile the source in your directory /cgi/bin and call it from your browser.

```
/* -----------------------------------------------------
ENVVARS.C
A simple program in C designed for working
in a CGI context - print the environment
variables.
-------------------------------------------------- */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//  m  a  i  n
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
char **pe;
printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n"
"<html>"
"<head>"
"<title>ENVVARS</title>"
"<body>"
"<h1>ENVVARS</h1>"
"<h3>My pid is: %d</h3>\n",getpid());
printf("<ul>");
for (pe=env; pe && *pe; pe++) printf("<li>%s<//li>\n",*pe);
printf("</ul>");
printf("</body></html>");
return 0;
} // end main
//////////////////// EOF //////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score -7):

Try the following code

```
function myIP() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php",false);
    xmlhttp.send();

    hostipInfo = xmlhttp.responseText.split("\n");

    for (i=0; hostipInfo.length >= i; i++) {
        ipAddress = hostipInfo[i].split(":");
        if ( ipAddress[0] == "IP" ) return ipAddress[1];
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: OP has clearly mentioned that no external links has to be used! `I do not want to use any link to get the IP.`

Comment: @ᴀʀᴜn BᴇrtiL Yes, codeMan  is right I have metion in my question that I do not want to use any external links

Comment: Javascript has no concept of self IP so you would have to use some external resource, even if that is another scripting language file on the same machine.

Comment: api.hostip.info is defunct.